# Hoverable / clickable tooltip using tooltip-is-open not working in directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Using ng-mouseover/ng-mouseleave together with tooltip-is-open to set the state of tooltip, i'm able to create a tooltip that is still open when hovered

However when I try to refactor it into a directive with

```
        element.on('mouseover', hoverIn);
        element.on('mouseleave', hoverOut);
```

the event fire but tooltip is still closed when mouse hover on tooltip region

Here's the plunker for both

https://plnkr.co/edit/6U2Dge8srf8C8SRNkPVK?p=preview

Edit : Using ng-mouseover/ng-mouseleave, it flickers when the mouse move out of the parent div into the child, so any suggestion to improve both is greatly welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to your issue.it's issue of scope update so you can forcefully update your scope using `$apply`
You can change your hoverIn and hoverOut function

```
hoverIn = function () {
    scope.tooltipState = true; // remove isOpen from here
    scope.$apply(); // force to apply scope
    console.log("Event Fired");
};

hoverOut = function () {
    scope.tooltipState = false; // remove isOpen from here
    scope.$apply(); // force to apply scope
    console.log("Event Fired");
};
```

Here is update plnkr [update plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qCRA39H3ynq99Gmkiy66?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I marked the answer.
However, we still have the problem of flickering. I created a separate question for it, maybe you can help providing some insight?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805846/mouseover-mouseenter-flickers-interaction-with-tooltip