# Mouseover / Mouseenter flickers interaction with tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The mouseover listens on the parent element, but when moving into the tooltip (child) element, it flickers. 
The console log show as if mouseover / mouseenter event is fired rapidly

Mouseenter does not keep tooptip display at all

```
  element.on('mouseenter', hoverIn); // or mouseover
  element.on('mouseleave', hoverOut);
```

Is this issue angularjs / jquery / bootstrap specific ?

How can it be better handled?

You can test it out with [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ew7NZwX1w3cqyteZBU40?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no jQuery in your demo. Then, I think, the cause of the issue is the race condition between setting `tooltipState` in your directive

```
scope.tooltipState = false;
scope.$apply();
```

and handling the `tooltipState` attribute by the bootstrap `uib-tooltip` directive. That become more obvious if you remove `scope.$apply()`: both directives are fighting for `tooltipState` and `scope.$apply()` just makes it a bit more streamlined.

To solve it I would try to use `uib-tooltip-template` option and set up custom `tool-tip` directive on the bootstrap's tooltip element itself. Then I would handle **only** `mouseleave` event and would drop the `tooltipState` flag when we are leaving the tooltip. Also, using `event.relatedTarget` we may not drop the `tooltipState` flag if the target is button.

Comment: There was indeed some racing condition to set the tooltipState flag
However, after looking at the documentation I found one easy way to fix that using tooltip-trigger. I created another answer
This answer helped me though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pointer-events: none;` in your `.tooltip.right`

[Docs for pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: This kills the tooltip when you are on the tooltip but out of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Just give toolTip 'tooltip-placement="right" ' to span.

```
<span tool-tip tooltip-state="tooltipState" tooltip-
placement="right">
<button uib-tooltip = '{{text}}'
tooltip-is-open="tooltipState"
type="button" class="btn btn-default">
Hoverable Tooltip Directive
</button>
</span>
```

Because its given to button(inner element/child), its flickering.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution for this is to set

```
tooltip-trigger="none"
```

I checked the documentation and it says tooltip-trigger by default listen to 'mouseenter'. May be that's the reason why there are multiple directives trying to set the value for tooltipState

Setting it to 'none' achieve what I desired

Updated [Plnrk](https://plnkr.co/edit/kpEqZ2LbexidhzfmhjO1?p=preview)